# Need some advice on MVC separation

Tags: php, zend-framework

I should note I am using Zend Framework. Although this shouldn't affect the concrete answer, it does mean there are several places I can implement my following method (action helper, controller etc).

The issue is I have buildOptions() and parseOptions() method which takes $_GET/$_POST variables based on a 'tag' and builds rules which are then used in a select query. An example would be ?modelSort=id&modelOrder=asc

The 'model' in the above obviously relates to the particular model, and it used as a 'tag' so that I can for example also have model2Sort and model2Order so there is no conflict between parameters.

However, the trouble I am having now is where should these methods go? They are generally dealing with request params. I have been reading a lot about fat model, thin controller. Should this be in an abstract model. My thinking was that if it were, I would do something like:

(note, I know I wouldn't call directly like this. Method would be used by child classes)

$abstractModel->buildOptions($params);

Where 'params' could be anything, like the request parameters $_GET or $_POST:

$abstractModel->buildOptions($_GET);

Now from what I can see the model is not inherintly dealing with request variables but rather parameters passed to the method.

Advice? Where does this method belong? Model, Controller?

Specifically on Zend, should it be an action helper, plugin, within an abstract model?

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: You are over thinking it. Just don't forget the security side of your methods. Prevent me from adding my own keys and values, which it sounds like your method cannot do.

Comment: I don't think I am overthinking it. I think if I choose one method over another I could cause lots of problems down the line. It is my understanding that models do not deal with request objects.. my method is not in concrete, what it currently does isn't of much importance. I just included some details to illustrate a use case. Could apply this question to any method which deals with request params which should be fed to a select query.

Comment: I guess I have been through the same question/doubt many times. However, I was not much aware of the "fat model thin controller" approach till today and I read a little  here - http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/the.model#zfbook.the.model.in.programming.fat.models.are.preferable.to.size.zero.models

Comment: Imho, when I have similar request processing in multiple controller actions I just create a controller action helper and call it like this at the beginning of those actions: $this->_helper->parseRequestParams($this->getRequest()->getPost());

Comment: If there are more actions with similar request parameters processing, I would probably move it from the action helper to a controller plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I like to think about it

```
Controller:
  Collect user input
  Sanitize input
  Instantiate model
  model->doStuff( cleaned user input )
  Instantitate view
  view->buildPrettyHtml( model )
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's pretty much two different ways to view MVC.  You can either do Controller-Push (where the controller pushes the data into the view) or View-Pull (where the view pulls the data it needs from the model).  Both methods have their pluses and minuses.   But the common theme is that the model is dumb to user input.  You should ask it for what the user requests.  This makes it much easier to re-use your model methods in different views (if you need to).

I personally like the View-Pull method since it allows you to easily re-use your views (since you don't need to worry about what data you need to push into it).  Therefore, your controller should deal with non-display user interaction (updating tables, etc).  But the View should be responsible for display-related user-interaction.  So if you buy that methodology, the sorting and pagination should be read by the view and it's the view's job to tell the model about it.  I like to keep my models fairly light so that they are as re-usable as possible.

But the big thing is not where you put it.  It's about consistency.  As long as you're consistent about the line of separation in your application, you won't have a problem.  The problem comes in where half the time you do it in one place, and the other half you do it in another.  So pick a method, and stick to it.

As with most things of this nature, a lot of it depends on personal preference and personal experience.  There is no single best method (if there was, we'd all be doing it).  Learn about the pros and cons of each, and choose for yourself (so that you understand the reasons for and against what you are doing).

Best of luck...

Comment: @Richard: Hence why there are options.  Out of curiosity, why do you like it better?

Comment: Actually there is no sound reason for that. I have always used Controller-Push and I only read about the other way (View-Pull) so it's very subjective. I am already too comfortable with my way of doing things (setting all view data in controller actions). Unless I will see some real benefit I don't think I am going to switch.

Comment: I must say, I do prefer controller-push. But thank you for introducing me to new ways of looking at MVC!